# Why is NServiceBus configuration broken after using TypesToScan()

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I have a Console app within which you can specify parameters, based on the parameters specified various handlers will be loaded. For instance:

```
prgm.exe nyse 
prgm.exe nasdaq
```

The goal is that within my code I have `INyseHandlers` and `INasdaqHandlers` and in the first case only any handlers extending the former are loaded, similarly for the case of the latter. The goal is to have one program which can listen to various or all sources depending on how it is run. To achieve this, I have set up my interfaces as mentioned above. Then in my configuration set up:

```
var configuration = new BusConfiguration();
configuration.InitializeStepBusConventions(); // extension method, not the problem

// Load all the handlers specified in command line arguments
if (!Args.Contains("any") && Args.Length != 0)
{
    List<Type> handlersToLoad = new List<Type>();

    foreach (var argument in Args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Adding {0} subscribers to loaded handlers. . .", argument.ToUpper());

        switch (argument)
        {
            case "nyse":
                AddToHandlerList(handlersToLoad, typeof(INyseProcessor));
                break;
            case "nasdaq":
                AddToHandlerList(handlersToLoad, typeof(INasdaqProcessor));
                break;        
        }
    }

    configuration.TypesToScan(handlersToLoad);
}

configuration.UseContainer<NinjectBuilder>(c => c.ExistingKernel(Kernel));
configuration.EndpointName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Defaults.Project.DefaultEndPointName]);
NServiceBus.Logging.LogManager.Use<NLogFactory>();

Bus.Create(configuration).Start();
```

And where:

```
private void AddToHandlerList(List<Type> handlersToLoad, Type interfaceType)
{
    List<Type> classesWhichExtendInterface = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(t)).ToList();
    classesWhichExtendInterface.Remove(interfaceType);

    handlersToLoad.AddRange(classesWhichExtendInterface);
}
```

Types are loaded as expected, that `List` is fine. But when I run this and get to the `Bus.Start` line I get the following error:

```
The given key (NServiceBus.LocalAddress) was not present in the dictionary.
```

Without the type loading, default behavior works fine and all the processors within the assembly are loaded. Why am I getting this error after running the `TypesToScan()` line?

EDIT: Here is the extension method:

```
config.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();
config.UseTransport<RabbitMQTransport>();

config.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();
config.EnableInstallers();

return config;
```

Comment: I think by doing that you only allow it to get your handlers and everything else like messages, transports, configurations, are removed.

Comment: I think that's a fair assumption, it seems that `TypesToScan` assumes you are starting from scratch and completely scraps the remainder of the default settings. Any idea how I would retrieve the ones necessary to make it functional?

Comment: I am not sure. I would propose to remove unneeded handlers when the list is already populated but I am not sure when it would be the right intersection to place this code. I still think splitting handlers to two different project would be the easiest.

Comment: That error message is a weird one, it get's thrown when a config setting can't be found in the in-memory `Overrides` or `Defaults` setting collections. Just out of curiosity, what transport mechanism are you using, as `NServiceBus.Local` isn't a key in the core assembly (unless it's hidden somewhere)?

Comment: Using RabbitMQ as a transport layer

Comment: I just tested a similar scenario using TypesToScan and it worked as expected in a console application. Anything else you can share?

Comment: Strange...not really. That's almost the entire console app posted above (except the handlers themselves, these all extend `IHandleMessages<>` and `INyseProcessor` or the like). I made an edit so that my extension method is more transparent but that's about it

Comment: Found another question, which shows the same error message, albeit in a different scenario, Udi's comment on there being of potential value to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27275494/nservicebus-5-with-rabbitmq-transport-throwing-exception-while-enabling-unicastb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your exception happens here

```
localAddress = Address.Parse(Settings.Get<string>("NServiceBus.LocalAddress"));
```

Settings get the "NServiceBus.LocalAddress" kvp set by a transport. Since you are not using the "Core" transport (MSMQ), I might suspect that your transport assembly types need to be included in TypesToScan, because of this:

```
ForAllTypes<Feature>(TypesToScan, t => featureActivator.Add(t.Construct<Feature>()));
```

I had a similar issue with using SQL Server transport, when I send a list of assemblies to With(assemblies) and did not include NServiceBus assemblies there, the transport failed to initialize. As soon as I added NServiceBus.* assemblies, everything started to work.

Comment: I am still slightly confused, I have references to `NServiceBus.Transports.RabbitMQ`, I was wondering if you could expand a little further?

Comment: You need to get types from that assembly and add them to your TypesToScan collection, like this handlersToLoad.AddRange(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (NServiceBus.Transports.RabbitMQ)).ExportedTypes)

Comment: This seems to be the right direction, after loading the following: `handlersToLoad.AddRange(Assembly.Load("NServiceBus.Transports.RabbitMQ").GetTypes());` the code no longer breaks, however the desired Handlers never execute, despite having been loaded. Should I also be loading `NServiceBus.Host` or `NServiceBus.Core` ?

Comment: Well, it's worth trying for sure :)

Comment: Tried, not quite there, still the fact that it isn't throwing errors is huge progress, I will work on this some more

Comment: Have you included your message types as well?

Comment: That was exactly it, had to include the message assembly

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add an answer for this for anyone who might find a similar situation to what I had, where I had this exact error when using `NServiceBus.Testing` to test a saga.

When you run `Test.Initialize` to set up your unit test, you can actually pass it some `BusConfiguration` setup, wherein you can specify which assemblies to scan.  I usually use the following as a standard setup, which prevents certain assembly loading issues if you're debugging a test (at least with NUnit):

```
Test.Initialize(conf => conf.AssembliesToScan(assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
```

However, for a reason unknown to me, today I was setting up a saga test and received the `NServiceBus.LocalAddress` error mentioned in this question.  I managed to solve that by adding an additional parameter to `AssembliesToScan`, as follows:

```
Test.Initialize(conf => conf.AssembliesToScan(
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
            Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()));
```

Hope this helps someone.